# Javascript Date gives wrong Timezone in Karma test

Tags: javascript, docker, gulp, timezone, phusion

Somehow after a Docker image rebuild, I started having problems with javascript timezone problem. It used to work, but after a Docker image update, somehow the resulting Date object does not obey the TZ setting anymore. As the result, our timezone depending Date string formatting tests are failing.

```
# in the tests
console.log(new Date("2016-04-01T00:00:00.000000+00:00"));
// It is very strange it says (Asia) at the end.
// In fact, it will say whatever I put in TZ
Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Asia)

# in Chrome developer tool
console.log(new Date());
Fri Apr 01 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

## gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('test', ['_set_tpe_timezone'], runKarmaWebpackTests);
gulp.task('_set_tpe_timezone', function() {
  gutil.log('Setting timezone TZ = Asia/Taipei');
  process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Taipei';
  return;
});
```

I am using the following setup to run javascript tests:

- Gulp + Karma
- inside a Docker container
- In gulpfile, execute the following setting before each test
  `process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Taipei';`
- using headless Chrome 59
- `cat /etc/timezone` = `Etc/UTC`

Comment: What is the `Dockerfile`? What command used to start the container for testing?

Comment: This would really benefit from a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The above is a start, but it is not verifiable.  Can you give us something that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: One thing I can tell you is that when you see `(Asia)` in the JS Date string, it means that the `TZ` variable was interpreted as a POSIX string, rather than as an IANA TZ identifier.  I can't tell you *why* without being able to reproduce the problem, but perhaps that will help somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. During the process of trying to get a reproducible MCVE, I found the problem is on the base image I used. I will post the answer to this question and send a bug report to the phusion/baseimage team.

Answer (score 0):

Although the root cause is not yet discovered, a solution was found. Since this problem did not appear before, but only after a `docker system prune -a`, the base image was updated to the latest, which introduce this bug.

As a temporary solution, I have switch back to the old base image and it works like before without other modifications. I am going to also report this to the phusion team.

## original Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage
...
```

## new Dockerfile

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.21
...
```